# Align lists with long sentences

Tags: indentation, enumerate, moderncv

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a really really really reall.....long sentence
\end{enumerate}

1. This is a really really really ....
....long sentence
```

I want it formatted like

```
1. This is a really really really ....
   ...long sentence
```

So it aligns with the words and not number. All the examples I've come across seem to show default behavior as the way I want it formatted, so I have a feeling its something defined in the `moderncv` class style I'm using.

**EDIT**
MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}  
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}
\cventry{2009-2014}{Graduate Research Assistant}{College Town}{MO}{USA}{%
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemindent}{.25in}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1mm}
\item Multi-state antibody design to interrogate mechanisms for antibody polyspecificity. How do antibodies use a limited sequence repertoire to bind many antigens? 
\end{enumerate}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I second @Werner's suggestion -- especially since the `enumerate` environment already seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to your preamble, you can specify adjustments to lists globally, or locally using an optional argument to `enumerate`. I've used the latter below by setting `leftmargin` rather than our item indentation (formally known as the `itemindent` key in `enumitem`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}
\cventry{2009-2014}{Graduate Research Assistant}{College Town}{MO}{USA}{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Multi-state antibody design to interrogate mechanisms for antibody polyspecificity. 
    How do antibodies use a limited sequence repertoire to bind many antigens? 
  \end{enumerate}%
}
\cventry{2009-2014}{Graduate Research Assistant}{College Town}{MO}{USA}{%
  \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1mm,topsep=0pt,leftmargin=.25in]
    \item Multi-state antibody design to interrogate mechanisms for antibody polyspecificity. 
    How do antibodies use a limited sequence repertoire to bind many antigens? 
  \end{enumerate}%
}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can add other adjustments as well (see the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for this).

Comment: so it was item ident that was causing it to act like that?

Comment: @jwillis0720: Yes. There are a number of lengths (horizontal and vertical) at play when considering lists. The [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) describes these in detail. Your choice of adjusting `\itemindent` was incorrect, since you wanted not just the `indent` associated with the `item` marker to move, but the entire block of text (i.e., the `leftmargin`).